# converting object of type Person toString()?

Tags: java, tostring

I'm trying to print out the details of a `Person` which contains an int and two Strings in my main method. I know I ave to use the `toString()` method but I can't remember how I would use this method to print out the details of each Person correctly. I'm assuming I must create a `toString()` method in my `Person` class and but I'm unsure as to what I must put into this. In my main method, I have put this:

```
System.out.println("Person: " + Person.Ben.toString());
System.out.println("Person: " + Person.Georgia.toString());
System.out.println("Person: " + Person.Tom.toString());
System.out.println("Person: " + Person.Beth.toString());
```

What would go inside of here to complete this?

```
public Person toString()
{
    //what goes here?
}
```

At the moment I'm getting this output:

```
Person: coursework.Person$1@15db9742
Person: coursework.Person$2@6d06d69c
Person: coursework.Person$3@7852e922
Person: coursework.Person$4@4e25154f
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: After looking at that question I agree I think it i a duplicate, sorry for not finding it before posting. I'd delete this if I could but I can't as it already has answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override [`Object#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--). Its signature:

```
public String toString()
```

Note that it returns a `String`, so you should be doing something like:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return this.name + " " + this.age;
}
```

Of course you can improve this as you wish, I just wrote it for demonstration.

---

It's worth mentioning the meaning of the output you're getting now. As stated in the docs:

> The `toString` method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character '@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:
>
> `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

Answer (score 1):

`toString` method comes from parent class called `java.lang.Object` and its signature is `public String toString()`, so your `toString` should be:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = ...
    sb.append("Name: ");
    sb.append(name);
    sb.append("Age: ");
    sb.append(age);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The `@Override` annotation is used to override a superclass's method.